# Insertion of an electric component in a resistance connected to AC supply

Tags: electricity, voltage

[image]Kindly ignore the written matter... I don't understand, how the current would remain the same even after a capacitor is introduced in the circuit...

This is what I did:

1. The current after insertion of capacitor would be '' I= V/X " where X is root of R^2+ 1/(wc)^2 net impedance.
2. Then after finding I... ''Vr =100V= I x R ''
3. What I get is $8$ micro farad.

It is wrong!

What's wrong in my approach?

Comment: The current is .5 A when the voltage is 110 V and you only have a bulb connected to the supply. If the 200 V supply was used with the bulb alone the current would be too high so a series capacitor is used to limit the current to 0.5 A.

Comment: @Farcher Ok.. But what's wrong in my approach?